# Merging strings with "%" in Python

Tags: python, string, int

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this bit of code and what to change?

```
number = 1
text = "hello"

while number <= 10:
    print("%d, %s" % number, text)
    number = number + 1
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "program.py", line 5, in
>   
>       print("%d, %s" % number + text) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

It works when I do it this way:

```
number = 1
text = "hello"

while number <= 10:
    print("%d" % number)
    number = number + 1
```

*I think i read somewhere that using the "%" sign to merge strings is the old way to do it, I'd like the code to still use it if it's possible.*

Comment: `% (number, text)`; note the parentheses.

Comment: `% (number, text)` --- you must pass a tuple

Comment: The error message and code are not for the same execution. Make sure to not misrepresent either.

Comment: @user2864740 Oh sorry about that, was going to ask something else and I didn't replace the text correctly, not gonna happen again.

Comment: `format` and `f`-strings are preferred for generating text now.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it this way requires parentheses around `number, text`, as it requires a tuple. So just replace the line `print("%d, %s" % number, text)` with `print("%d, %s" % (number, text))` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
number = 1
text = "hello"

while number <= 10:
    print("%d, %s" % (number, text))
    number = number + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In `print("%d, %s" % number, text)` statement, you need to provide a tuple of parameters to the string formatting (in your case "%d, %s"). So, the correct way to do this is -

```
print("%d, %s" % (number, text))
```

or

```
print number, text  # applicable for python 2.7
# print (number, text) # Python 3. Python 2.7 prints a tuple
```

The second one is applicable as you are not printing anything other that the variables.
For the first one you need a tuple for where you are providing more than one arguments during string formatting. So, if want to print say only number, you can do just `print ("%d" %number)` or `print "%d" %number`. The tuple in this case is not mandatory, but you can always do `print ("%d" %(number,))` if you really want to type some more characters.

But the first one is old way of doing things. For newer and more cooler version, use `format()` like below -

```
print("{}, {} blah blah blah".format(number, text))
```

or,

```
print "{}, {} blah blah blah".format(number, text)
```

For more info, check out - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Also follow the answer given by @lenik for other problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely against all the rules of the python code. Should have been written like this:

```
text = 'hello'
for number in range(10) :
    print( number, text )
```

1. No unneeded initializations for `number`
2. No `while` loop, which often leads to errors
3. No formatting where not necessary